# Django 4.0.1 django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet. when I run make migrations

Tags: django

I changed something in the `Request` model and tried running makemigrations and it is giving me this error

```
$python manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/raymond/Documents/GitHub/Management/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/raymond/Documents/GitHub/Management/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/raymond/opt/anaconda3/envs/python388/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 425, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/raymond/opt/anaconda3/envs/python388/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Users/raymond/opt/anaconda3/envs/python388/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/raymond/opt/anaconda3/envs/python388/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/Users/raymond/opt/anaconda3/envs/python388/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 300, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/Users/raymond/opt/anaconda3/envs/python388/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/raymond/Documents/GitHub/Management/request/models.py", line 7, in <module>
    class Request(models.Model):
  File "/Users/raymond/Documents/GitHub/Management/request/models.py", line 9, in Request
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, choices=[(u.username, u) for u in User.objects.filter(profile__teacher_status=True)], related_name='teacher')
  File "/Users/raymond/opt/anaconda3/envs/python388/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/raymond/opt/anaconda3/envs/python388/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 974, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, args, kwargs)
  File "/Users/raymond/opt/anaconda3/envs/python388/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 992, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone._filter_or_exclude_inplace(negate, args, kwargs)
  File "/Users/raymond/opt/anaconda3/envs/python388/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 999, in _filter_or_exclude_inplace
    self._query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/Users/raymond/opt/anaconda3/envs/python388/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1375, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "/Users/raymond/opt/anaconda3/envs/python388/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1396, in _add_q
    child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(
  File "/Users/raymond/opt/anaconda3/envs/python388/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1271, in build_filter
    lookups, parts, reffed_expression = self.solve_lookup_type(arg)
  File "/Users/raymond/opt/anaconda3/envs/python388/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1099, in solve_lookup_type
    _, field, _, lookup_parts = self.names_to_path(lookup_splitted, self.get_meta())
  File "/Users/raymond/opt/anaconda3/envs/python388/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1518, in names_to_path
    *get_field_names_from_opts(opts),
  File "/Users/raymond/opt/anaconda3/envs/python388/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 47, in get_field_names_from_opts
    for f in opts.get_fields()
  File "/Users/raymond/opt/anaconda3/envs/python388/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 778, in get_fields
    return self._get_fields(include_parents=include_parents, include_hidden=include_hidden)
  File "/Users/raymond/opt/anaconda3/envs/python388/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 838, in _get_fields
    all_fields = self._relation_tree
  File "/Users/raymond/opt/anaconda3/envs/python388/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/raymond/opt/anaconda3/envs/python388/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 751, in _relation_tree
    return self._populate_directed_relation_graph()
  File "/Users/raymond/opt/anaconda3/envs/python388/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 721, in _populate_directed_relation_graph
    all_models = self.apps.get_models(include_auto_created=True)
  File "/Users/raymond/opt/anaconda3/envs/python388/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 179, in get_models
    self.check_models_ready()
  File "/Users/raymond/opt/anaconda3/envs/python388/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 141, in check_models_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are accessing the User model in the Request declaration.

```
teacher = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, choices=[(u.username, u) for u in User.objects.filter(profile__teacher_status=True)], related_name='teacher')
```

as the teacher Field is a ForeignKey to User, you don't need to add the available choices choices in the model. If you really need this you can add this in the form you are using and add a [Constraint](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/constraints/) to the Request model.